# Where is libbinder since JellyBean?

Tags: android, android-binder

I saw libbinder code in the framework base code base `/libs/binder`. But since jellybean, libbinder is moved somewhere else and I could never find it. Nevertheless, I still find many libraries referencing it. I would like to know where it it now.

P.S. the libbinder code in 4.04r2.1 can be foud [here](https://code.google.com/p/android-source-browsing/source/browse/include/binder/Binder.h?repo=platform--frameworks--base&name=android-4.0.4_r2.1).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was moved to `frameworks/native/libs/binder`.